# How to find the partial derivative of $f(x, y) = x^{2} - y^{2}$ with respect to $y.$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Recently, I began exploring the realms of multi-variable calculus, and, already, I have ran into a problem.

I am trying to find the partial derivative of $f(x, y) = x^{2} - y^{2}$ with respect to $y$.

I believe it to be $-2y,$ but I am not sure, as Wolfram Alpha seems to be giving me [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%2C%20y%29%20%3D%20x%5E2%20-%20y%5E2%20partial%20derivative%20with%20respect%20to%20y) rather daunting result.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdy%20x%5E2%20-%20y%5E2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. You can make Wolfram Alpha show you this by [altering your input](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%20-%20y%5E2%20partial%20derivative%20with%20respect%20to%20y)

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you very much!

Comment: I will accept your answer in twelve minutes, as that is the first instance in which I can. Thank you for your help, Sloan.

Comment: May I ask, additionally, if the partial derivative of $f(x, y) = x + y$ with respect to $x$ would be $1$?

Comment: yes with respect to $x$ we get "1"

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner How about the partial derivative of $f(x, y) = x + y$ with respect to $y$? Would it also be $1$?

Comment: Yes, that is also $1$.

Comment: @Sloan Ah, thank you!

Comment: yes it is also be $1$

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, since if you derivate with respect to $y$, $x^2$ will count only as a constant, and the derivate of any constant is $0$. Since derivating is additive, you can do it by first derivating $x^2$, and then derivating $y^2$. The first will  be $0$, the second is $2y$, therefore your answer is $0-2y=-2y$. Totally correct. :)

Comment: No problem, I am happy I could help. :)